# Values wont reflect

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js

This is a very beginner level question as I just started to look at knockout js by downloading js,referring it in my web app.

My simple aspx code. based on first tutorial on knockout js site learning page.

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="KnockoutDemo.aspx.cs" Inherits="knockoutjs.KnockoutDemo" %>

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script src="javascripts/knockout-3.2.0.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
     <script type="text/javascript">

         function AppViewModel() {
             debugger;
             this.firstName = "XYZ";
             this.lastName = "UU";


         }

         function callKnockOut() {
             debugger;
             ko.applyBindings(new AppViewModel());
         }
     </script>
    <div>
    <p>First name: <strong data-bind="text: firstName"></strong></p>
    <p>Last name: <strong data-bind="text: lastName"></strong></p>
        <button id="click" onclick="callKnockOut();"></button>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

ideally the values should take effect after I click button.the code runs through successfully.labels won't show anything!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Knockout is client side javascript library, and you are submitting your form to server so instead of that don't run this at server run it to client i.e. dont write runat="server" for form tag. Then this will absolutely work.

```js
function AppViewModel() {
             debugger;
             this.firstName = "XYZ";
             this.lastName = "UU";
         }
         function callKnockOut() {
             debugger;
             ko.applyBindings(new AppViewModel());
         }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<form id="form1" action="#">
    <div>
    <p>First name: <strong data-bind="text: firstName"></strong></p>
    <p>Last name: <strong data-bind="text: lastName"></strong></p>
        <button id="click" onclick="callKnockOut();">submit</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: same result ,after removing runat="server" tag from form.Can knockout js work with asp.net web application ? (not an mvc application!)

Comment: You can check my code and output. Is it matching with what you need?